# Why .net maui App Crashing On iOS device?

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I have a .NET MAUI application installed on iPad (9th generation, ios 15.5). Application is .NET MAUI "Hello World" program that is present when a blank maui project is created.

The application does not load and only appears a splash screen for a few seconds.
I am unable to view any content in app

I also developed my .NET MAUI app and installed on ipad. This application behaves the same. I can't see any content from app and the splash screen is displayed 26s after lunch. After the 26s application crashed.

Has anyone had similar experiences running a .NET MAUI application on a real iOS device?
Both applications I mentioned debugged without problems in the ios simulator on the macBook device.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 preview version 17.4.0 preview 2.0

I am grateful for any answer and advice.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what exactly you are doing? Can you describe the different steps for others to be able to try and reproduce the issue? Do you receive any warnings, errors or exceptions in the debug Console window? There have been some issues recently with .NET MAUI on iOS, you might want to install VS 17.4 Preview 2.1 and also make sure you are using Xcode 13.4 on macOS

Comment: if the splash is displayed for 26s then it is hanging on startup and iOS is killing it

Comment: Check your Application output your apps being killed by the OS

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am trying to get the very small testpogram on the ipad. I have taken template program from empty maui project. I created .ipa file. I created provisioning profile development and added my ipad as device in profile. I installed .ipa file on ipad using xcode (by windows<devices and simularors). My application appears on ipad but it crashes after 26s. I see only splash screen. I can't see content of application. I have no warnings and errors messages by creating .ipa file. How can I analyze crash of application in ios device?

Comment: Did you try to test it on the ipad simulator or other ios device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed VS 17.4 Preview 2.1 and changed Target Framework for iOS to net7.0-ios. That solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your Maui .csproj file. I think It can help somebody.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Fixed my issue with the latest version of MAUI and Xcode